# Common approach to verifying if something is empty

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

I'm quite new to InSpec and would like to learn from your experience.

There are some approaches to verifying if a file or its property is empty.

**Approach 1** - using **file** resource to and read its content. Use **eq** matcher to check the output ''

```
describe file('file_path') do
  its(:contents) { should eq ' ' }
end
```

**Approach 2** - - using **file** resource to and read its content, but check null

```
describe file('file_path') do
  its(:contents) { should be nil }
end
```

**Approach 3 (uncommon)** - use **command** resource to execute the **cat** command

```
describe command('cat /etc/file_path') do
  its(:stdout) { should eq ' ' }
end
```

**Approach 4** - use **should be_empty**

```
describe file('file_path') do
  its(:contents) { should be_empty }
end
```

If there is any more approach, please feel free to suggest.

Is there a performance impact if using uncommon approach?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question.  It's a mini-tutorial.

Comment: This is a deep-dive technical question to understand the best approach to minimize performance impact. Not sure why you think it is mini-tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `its(:size) { should eq 0 }`? That avoids the need to actually transfer the contents.

Comment: Thank you for another approach which I didn't know. That works well!